# Powershell compare between Get-ChildItem and Get-Content objects

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare two object with same content but got opposite result. Something wrong in my code, I think it something with objects definitions.
Thank you for help.

```
$get_child = Get-ChildItem d:\temp | Select-Object Name 
$get_child | Out-File d:\temp1\files.txt 
$get_content = Get-Content d:\temp1\files.txt 

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $get_child -DifferenceObject $get_content 

------Output------------------------------------------------ 

PS> $get_child 

Name 
---- 
1.txt
2.txt


PS> $get_content

Name 
---- 
1.txt
2.txt


PS> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $get_child  -DifferenceObject $get_content

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
Name        =>           
----        =>           
1.txt       =>           
2.txt       =>           
            =>
```

Comment: Run `$get_child | Get-Member` and `$get_content | Get-Member` and you'll see the difference. The two objects are not of the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is kind of an illusion.  The appearance is the same, but with other commands you can see how they're different.  The first one is a 2 element pscustomobject array, and the second one is a 6 element string array.  .gettype() is a super useful method.

```
PS /Users/js/foo> $get_child | foreach { $_.gettype() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

PS /Users/js/foo> $get_content | foreach { $_.gettype() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand.
How can I fix the get_child object, so I can compare it with get_content?